# How to update Ionic2 to latest/master Angular2?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I'm developing an app using Ionic2 from github/master.

What would be the best way to update it to the latest angular2 (latest release or master) if I want to get latest fixes from there?

Comment: Your best option so far is following the [Developer guide](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md). You will want to track this issue as well ([#4671](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4671)).

Comment: The links you provided while valuable does not answer my question as they are for Angular2 rather then Ionic2. I'm not sure where the Ionic takes the ng2 from (there are some bundles inside Ionic2 dist) and how to make it to use the latest ng2 master.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they [install it](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2/blob/master/package.json#L24) like everybody else. If you want to update Ionic2 to latest master you should see this [issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2/issues/438)

Comment: Yeah, that's mine. I just new to NPM/package/dependency management but slowly getting it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install master version you can do it with:

> `npm install --save ionic-angular@nightly`

Instead if you want to build your dist you can:

> `clone https://github.com/driftyco/ionic.git`
>
> `cd ionic`
>
> `npm install`
>
> `gulp watch`

For more info: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/scripts/README.md

Answer (score 1):

It's best to keep everything in sync for the moment. We're working on our release process and are hoping to have nightly builds released soon so that you can just pull the latest and greatest very quickly.